# click on list and expand a box

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a list of items that each list contain a box which is hidden by default and after click on each list the box should be shown.

Now the problem is after expanding a list other list item will be expanded as well.

please check the image : [image]

Is there any way that I can expand only the item that gets clicked ?

```
<li>
  user name test
  <div class="content">
    <span>
      A card can be used to display content related to 
      a single subject. The content can consist of multiple 
      elements of varying types and sizes.
    </span>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  user name test
  <div class="content">
    <span>
      A card can be used to display content related to 
      a single subject. The content can consist of multiple 
      elements of varying types and sizes.
    </span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8qLt3wru/4/

Comment: No. That is not the way flexbox works. You are expanding the row so naturally the other items in the row take the row height

Comment: @Paulie_D what about other ways ? any suggestion ?

Comment: Seems like [the disclosure element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) would fit this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One fix would be to use the HTML `<details>` disclosure and the CSS like so:

```css
details {
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
    display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary>Details</summary>
    This is an example of the details disclosure.
</details>
<details>
    <summary>Details</summary>
    This is an example of the details disclosure.
</details>
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Answer (score -1):

If you're wanting the SPAN text to show but not push the other elements down, you'd have to overlap it.  This example goes off of Bauke's suggestion.

CSS:

```
    summary{cursor:pointer}
    summary:focus{outline:none}

    details{display:inline-block}
    details > span{background:#f0f0f0;position:absolute;width:400px;}
    details > summary {list-style:none;}
    details > summary::-webkit-details-marker {display:none}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width:400px">

    <li>
        <details closed>
            <summary>user name test A</summary>
            <span>
                A card can be used to display content related to 
                a single subject. The content can consist of multiple 
                elements of varying types and sizes.
            </span>
        </details>
    </li>
    <li>
        <details closed>
            <summary>user name test A</summary>
            <span>
                A card can be used to display content related to 
                a single subject. The content can consist of multiple 
                elements of varying types and sizes.
            </span>
        </details>
    </li>

</div>
```

Comment: but i don't want to overlap it i just want to make it visible and without push others item

Comment: Then you'd probably have to set a fixed size for the block elements so that the spacing between stays constant when it's shown or hidden apart from the rest. In other words, "user name test" needs enough space around it to display the hidden details so when it is shown it's not having to push any elements around.